# Number of New Products Displayed in Magento Home CMS Page

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am using

```
{
    {
        block type="catalog/product_new" 
        name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage"
        template="catalog/product/new.phtml"
    }
}
```

in cms page to show new products. Now it is showing only one product.

Is there any way to change it to show a specified number of products? eg : 16 products

Comment: Can you show the contents of `template/catalog/product/new.phtml`?  It should show more than one product by default.  Are you using a custom template?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I was not able to paste entire code here so I had to upload it to MediaFire. Here is the link : http://www.mediafire.com/?uwp1xu4g2caj29q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in my site.  Open `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php`

Around line 38 you should see something like this:

```
const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 5;
```

Chances are that number is set to "1".  If not then look in `/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php` to make sure someone didn't create a local override of your core file.

If the number is "1" then you should create a module to change that value that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" num_products="9" category_id="231" template="catalog/product/list_no_toolbar.phtml" columnCount="3"}}
```

num_products is the param where you say how many products to show on that page.

in app/code/local create Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List
In your new List directory create the following file called Random.php

```
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();
            if($categoryID)
            {
              $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
              $category->load($categoryID); // this is category id
              $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
            } else
            {
              $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            }
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 3;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

*$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');* is the line that set random, you can comment this out.